# Multiple views in one page issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have three views that, by themselves, work fine.  We'll call them A, B, and C.  They need to stand by themselves as full, independent views.

That said, on view A, I always need to display B and C.  That's easy enough, using jquery.load().  They're displaying great and everything 'looks' good.  The problem comes when I submit.  I haven't done anything quite like this.  There are three 'submit' buttons' for the three forms.  I can easily hide all but the one for page A.  But, **in the controller, how do I also submit B and C when I submit A?**  I don't know if it matters but all three are strictly typed views.

I'm using C#, MVC 4, LINQ to SQL.

Thanks

Comment: How about having a single submit button on page and viewmodel comprising models of different views as properties.

Comment: I'll look into that, thank you.

I think I can do it but one piece is stumping me right now

            `var a = db.GetB(id);`
            `if (ModelState.IsValid) {`
                `UpdateModel(a);`
                `db.SubmitChanges();`
                `return View(id);`
            `}`

That's basically what I'm doing for view A.  How do I say something equivalent for "UpdateModel(b)" when the page's model is not relating to B?

Comment: Since page can be submitted only once, we need to capture all the values i.e., a, b and c at one go. So, by having a ViewModel class with properties {a,b,c} will capture all the values.

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  If you make that your answer I will check it.

Comment: I've provided suggestion, so it would be better you post your pseudo code how actually you've implemented it and mark it as answer.

Comment: Right now I'm still stuck.  B has several rows of data to submit, whereas A and C have only one.

Comment: Can you post the UI of the main view, how you're loading this views and atleast one view, A and its actions.